Can't use FireFox in Digital Ocean
I've successfully installed ubuntu in a droplet for digital ocean. Everything works except for Firefox. I can't type in the bar. I tried removing it as well, but despite removing it via the command line, it's still present. I've rebooted a couple of times, it has the latest upgrades, etc. I'm just not able to type in Firefox and delete it. Anyone else had this problem? I'm also about to install another browser but this was a problem.
